# HTML5 canvas drawImage, how to preserve image source size

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas

```
function getImageBase64Data(_id)
{   
    var c = document.createElement('CANVAS');
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    var img = document.getElementById(_id);
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    var dataURL = c.toDataURL();
    return dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
}
```

I'm using HTML5 canvas to obtain base64-encoded image data. However, the resulting base64 encoded string is different and smaller than encoding the original image file with external software.

I suspect what is drawn on the canvas is the the resized/compressed image data rendered on the page, not the original source data. Is this the case, and how could I obtain the original bytes of the image? It is essential, that original bytes aren't manipulated in any way.

Comment: Yes, drawing an image on the canvas will alter its data, but here the main problem is that you are not setting the size of your canvas, which will default to 300*150px. Start by setting `c.width = img.naturalWidth; c.height = img.naturalHeight` so you get at least same sized images.

Comment: By setting size of the canvas, resulting image has right dimensions, but only small portion of image is rendered

Comment: uh? And you are still calling it with `drawImage(img, 0,0)`?

Comment: It was stupid mistake. I just printed the base64 string in console and copied it, and didn't noticed that IE truncated the string... When console prints the function's return value, it even includes the enclosing quote, so I couldn't know the string was truncated. In chrome console I was able to print the whole string!

Answer (score 0):

To make it shown without compress, change the height/width for canvas itself:

```
var img = new Image(); // var img = document.getElementById(_id);
img.onload = function() {
    var c = document.createElement('canvas');
    c.width = img.width;
    c.height = img.height;
    // ... other stuff        
};
```

Comment: Then it's cropping, not compressing. In most cases, `canvas.toDataURL()` without param will actually decompress the image